# Matlab unable to plot validation and testing on neural network

Tags: matlab, validation, testing, plot, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on time-series prediction using Recurrent Neural Network (matlab).
I am using 'divideind' for RNN. But the problem I face is unable plotting the validation and testing data I have divided. The only plot showing up is training data.

So, I have tried to copy my code for dividing data using Backpropagation method. The code works fine. The plot works fine showing the regression and time-series response of training, validation, and testing data.

Here's my code

```
net = layrecnet(1:1,7,'trainlm');
........

% divide data
net.divideFcn = 'divideind';  % divide data by indexing
[trainIndex,valIndex,testIndex] = divideind(1117,1:781,782:949,950:1117);
net.divideParam.trainInd = trainIndex;
net.divideParam.valInd = valIndex;
net.divideParam.testInd  = testIndex;

.......

[inpt,inputStates,layerStates,trgts]=preparets(net,Xcell,Ycell);
net=train(net,inpt,trgts,inputStates,layerStates);

resultTest = net(inpt,inputStates,layerStates);
errorTest = gsubtract(luaran,resultTest);
perf = perform(net,resultTest,trgts);
```

I expect I can see the regression and time-series response plot of validation and testing data. 
As I mentioned earlier, the only plot I see is for training data only.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic networks (as layrecnet) you should use this additional line:

```
net.divideMode = 'time'; % 'time' for dynamic networks or 'sample' for static networks
```